# C++ Boost Graph Library:- Specifying Root Node for a DFS

Tags: c++, depth-first-search, boost-graph

Using the standard on a directed graph,

```
std::vector<size_type> dtime(N);
std::vector<size_type> ftime(N);
size_type t = 0;
dfs_time_visitor<size_type*> vis(&dtime[0], &ftime[0], t);
depth_first_search(graph, visitor(vis));
```

appears to always start the dfs from node 0.

How does one tell the algorithm to start from a known "root node"?

Comment: The first error message says `g` is undefined.  What is `g`?

Comment: My fault. Was code from a few lines above this function call, related to something else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Here](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/doc/depth_first_search.html) you can find a list of all the overloads for `depth_first_search`. The one you need is the "[named parameter](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/doc/bgl_named_params.html) version". The parameter you need to use is "root_vertex" and your invocation of `depth_first_search` would simply be:

```
depth_first_search(graph, visitor(vis).root_vertex(root_vertex_descriptor));
```

Comment: Just tried that, and got a compile error...Have edited OP to reflect that.

Comment: Sorry guys, but fault. I had a couple of lines of code above this function call that relates to something else. Thanks for the help, much appreciated. I find the reference material for Boost Graph really hard to understand / find what I am looking for and few examples that aren't just running a very basic call. Add in the seemingly unreadable compiler errors if you make a mistake.

Comment: what is the difference between `dfs_time_visitor` and regular dfs_visitor ?